# Ubuntu 18.04 external audio sources not recognized

Tags: nvidia, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

Nothing other than the built in speaker is displayed.

I have tried `pavucontrol`, `pulseaudio -k`, updating nvidia drivers etc. Even when I pair my phone through bluetooth it displays in the input tab but not the output.

Specs:

- Lenovo Y720
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nvidia 1060 6GB
- Intel 15-7300HQ

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] for clarification: What external audio sources? Are you talking about "sources" as in inputs or do you mean outputs? You mentioned Nvidia drivers but NVIDIA HDMI/DP is only output. And what do you expect to happen with the phone connected by Bluetooth?